# Capture a repeated regex rule in separate groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a log line that I'm trying to create capture groups for. It looks like this:

```
level=warning;key=value1;key=value2;ts=2022-03-23T11:55:45.219678992Z;key=value3;system=input_service.go:64;key=dnb;msg=running;module=server;key=value4
```

[This is the regex](https://regex101.com/r/cASWTe/1) I've tried so far:

```
(key=(?P<key1>\w+))|(key=(?P<key2>\w+))|(key=(?P<key3>\w+))|(key=(?P<key4>\w+))
```

It seems to capture the "`key`" values, however they all seem to be grouped under the the same group "`key1`". I want each one to be in it's own separate one.

I also want to create a regex that will still work even if there is only 1 key, and not 4, so that it can still match on just this line:

```
level=warning;key=value1
```

Is it possible?
Appreciate any guidance here. Thank you.

Comment: use `re.findall` with `key=(\w+)` pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) :

```
# assuming `log` is holding a string
out = re.findall(r"key=(\w+)(?=;|$)", log)
```

Or, as suggested by @*[pts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97248/pts)*, with [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) inside a *listcomp* :

```
out = [m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r"key=(\w+)(?=;|$)", log)]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

#['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'dnb', 'value4']
```

Comment: Also there is *finditer*, which yields match objects, from which it's easy to retrieve individual `(...)` group matches.

Comment: Nice one @pts, I updated my answer ;)